# create multiple language joomla modules

Tags: php, xml, joomla

I create a modules for joomla that support multiple language in fond-end and back-end.frond-end is fine and i have not problem in front-end.but language option not working in back-end.i have added some parameter in `.xml` file inside config tag to get data from admin.in the label i put string and consider value for that string in language file. section config and section language of my `.xml` file is:

```
<config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="show_type" type="checkbox" label="MOD_MYMODULE_SHOW_TYPE" />
        </fields>
    </config>
    <languages folder="path/to/language">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
```

in `en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini` file I put this line :

```
MOD_MYMODULE_SHOW_TYPE = "show type"
```

But it does not work.how i should put language variable in `.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You have to add language file constants in `en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini` not in `en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini`

```
MOD_MYMODULE_SHOW_TYPE = "show type"
```

should be add inside `en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini` file

you can download a working sample from [here](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-virtuemart-product-image-zoom)

Hope its works..